# Use input lines from file for unix grep

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a file on my filesystem which has a a number of pids in it. Each pid is on a new line. For example...

```
26011
26013
26016
26017
```

I would like to do a 'ps -eaf | grep pid' for each of the pids in the file using a single command.

Can someone help me with how I can use the input pids from the file but also for each line in the file.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all the pids in a file, you can use `grep -f` to use it as a pattern itself:

```
ps -eaf | grep -f file
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>
> Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
>   contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

Comment: Good one, I had forgot about this option :)

Comment: thank you. This is definitely the best/easiest solution in my view.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
for pid in `cat temp.pids`; do ps -eaf | grep $pid; done
```

where temp.pids is the file containing the PIDs one per line

Comment: @Richie This solution makes sense, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes it did make sense to me. You are running my command in a loop. This is actually what I thought that I would have to do and thank you for the answer. I think however the grep -f is the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
ps -ef | grep -E "$(cat pids.txt | tr '\n' '|' | head -c -1)"
```

This will concat all the pids together with pipes and use it as the regex to grep

Comment: this is kind of overkilling for something `grep -f` alone does.

Comment: I hadn't used grep -f before, it looks cool.  However, when I test it I'm getting very different results than my approach.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Uhms, weird. It should be the same: `-f` gets the regexs from the file, your approach "builds" them. I don't have a good environment to check now, I will do tomorrow